# Reversing code, large fs:18h meaning

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows

I'm trying to reverse this code on windows,
what those lines mean?

```
mov     eax, large fs:18h
mov     eax, [eax+30h]
```

and

```
fldz
fstenv  [esp+var_1C]
```

**full code:**

```
mov     eax, large fs:18h
mov     eax, [eax+30h]
push    eax
movzx   eax, byte ptr [eax+2]
call    unkfunc
jnz     loc_4031ED
```

unkfunc:

```
var_1C= byte ptr -1Ch

fldz
fstenv  [esp+var_1C]
jmp     short test_eax_eax
```

test_eax_eax:

```
test eax,eax
ret
```

Comment: Fs:18 teb  ; +30 = ptr ti peb ; + 2 = isdebugged

Comment: @blabb why don't you create a proper answer, this comment of yours has almost all qualities of a good answer already.

Comment: @VitalyOsipov it is tedious to type answers from a teenie weenie screen :)

Comment: the fldz/fstenv is a way to get the EIP address without using call/pop method

Answer (score 3):

As I commented code is checking `BeingDebugged` member of `ProcessEnvironmentBlock`  structure
`_PEB` is a memebr of `ThreadEnvironemntBlock` structure `_TEB`
the call is probably junk / anyway it doesn't alter eax ie eax will not be 0 if you are debugging

**0:000> r fs**

```
fs=0000003b
```

**0:000> dd /c 1 [3b:18]  L?0x1**

```
003b:00000018  7ffdf000
```

**0:000> ? $teb**

```
Evaluate expression: 2147348480 = 7ffdf000
```

**0:000> dd /c 1 poi([3b:18])+0x30  L?0x1**

```
7ffdf030  7ffd3000
```

**0:000> ? @$peb**

```
Evaluate expression: 2147299328 = 7ffd3000
```

**0:000> db /c 1 poi(poi([3b:18])+0x30)  L?0x3**

```
7ffd3000  00  .
7ffd3001  00  .
7ffd3002  01  .
```

**0:000> ?? @$peb->BeingDebugged**

```
unsigned char 0x01 ''
```

**0:000> ? @@c++(&(@$peb->BeingDebugged))**

```
Evaluate expression: 2147299330 = 7ffd3002
```

**0:000> db (poi((@$teb + @@(#FIELD_OFFSET(ntdll!_TEB,ProcessEnvironmentBlock))))) + @@(#FIELD_OFFSET(ntdll!_PEB,BeingDebugged)) l?@@(#RTL_FIELD_SIZE(ntdll!_PEB,BeingDebugged))**

```
7ffd3002  01
```

some more :)

```
0:000> db (poi((poi(3b:18) + @@(#FIELD_OFFSET(ntdll!_TEB,ProcessEnvironmentBlock))))) + @@(#FIELD_OFFSET(ntdll!_PEB,BeingDebugged)) l?@@(#RTL_FIELD_SIZE(ntdll!_PEB,BeingDebugged))
7ffd3002  01                                               .
0:000> db (poi((poi(@fs:18) + @@(#FIELD_OFFSET(ntdll!_TEB,ProcessEnvironmentBlock))))) + @@(#FIELD_OFFSET(ntdll!_PEB,BeingDebugged)) l?@@(#RTL_FIELD_SIZE(ntdll!_PEB,BeingDebugged))
7ffd3002  01
```

forgot to mention the new born baby viz natvis

```
0:000> dx &Debugger.State.PseudoRegisters.General.teb[0],1

0x7ffdf000 [Type: _TEB *]
    [0]              [Type: _TEB]

0:000> dx &Debugger.State.PseudoRegisters.General.teb->ProcessEnvironmentBlock

0x7ffdf030 [Type: _PEB * *]
    0x7ffda000 [Type: _PEB *]

0:000> dx &Debugger.State.PseudoRegisters.General.teb->ProcessEnvironmentBlock->BeingDebugged

0x7ffda002 : 0x1 [Type: unsigned char *]
    0x1
                                       .
```